# After namenode is in safe mode and back again normal ,twitter stream api does not work

Tags: hadoop, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, flume, twitter-streaming-api

Our twitter stream api was working good till namenode mode became safe mode(cause of limited free space in var directory) after removing a few logs.We started flume job but getting this error.

```
16/07/22 14:58:29 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Waiting for 240000   milliseconds
16/07/22 15:02:29 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Establishing connection.
16/07/22 15:02:30 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I controlled system clock it is correct also our tokens are working too.How can i fix this?